# Memory usage is very high

Tags: zalenium

We have Zalenium installed on an Azure Linux VM that has: 16 vcpu and 64Gb memory
We have configured Zalenium with:
- Max 10 containers
- Max tests per container = 10
- Video recording = Only Failed Tests

When we execute 10 tests in parallel, we are noticing the memory usage is about 10Gb but the CPU usage is at 70%.

This high usage of resources will affect our ability to scale beyond 10 containers, as the Azure cost will be too high.

My question is, has anyone else seen such high resource usage, and is there any advice on how to bring that down?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is normal, each container uses in average 1GB of RAM and 1 CPU (2CPUs if video recording is enabled). Memory consumption also depends on how heavy the site under test is.